# "unexpected '}', expecting =>" while using attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have an `img` tag as html and I want to use it in erb:

```
<img src="images/Slider/app.png" alt="" width="636" height="441" data-ww="['600px','500px','400px','200px']" data-hh="['338px','281px','225px','113px']" data-no-retina>
```

my html erb code is:

```
<%= image_tag "/Slider/app.png", width:"636", height:"441", data: { ww:['600px','500px','400px','200px'], hh:['338px','281px','225px','113px'], no-retina } %>
```

but I get syntax error: `unexpected '}', expecting =>`

Comment: `no-retina` is not a key value pair. It cannot be inside the Hash

Comment: putting it out of the hash does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does not allow dash-case as a hash key. Thus the syntax is failing when trying to parse `no-retina`.

You should use lateral strings if you want to have a dash-case as a key

```
<%= image_tag "/Slider/app.png", width:"636", height:"441", data: { ww:['600px','500px','400px','200px'], hh:['338px','281px','225px','113px'], 'no-retina': true } %>
```

In this particular case (image_tag helper and data attributes), however, Rails is smart enough to get you the right HTML if you just use uderscores:

```
<%= image_tag "/Slider/app.png", width:"636", height:"441", data: { ww:['600px','500px','400px','200px'], hh:['338px','281px','225px','113px'], no_retina: true } %>
```

Also if you looks at the [image_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag) documentation, you will see that you can use `size` to specify height and width. With some code style cleanup this is what looks much better:

```
<%= image_tag "/Slider/app.png", size: "636x441", data: { ww: ['600px','500px','400px','200px'], hh: ['338px','281px','225px','113px'], no_retina: true } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break it by `-` and nest it

```
<%= image_tag "/Slider/app.png", data: { no: { retina: true } } %>
```